# How to increase maximum file upload size in php

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

I have tried almost everything e.g,

Tried to change value of **post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize** in both files **php.ini-dist** and **php.ini-recommended**

Also

Tries to create php.ini file and pasting **post_max_size = 10M , upload_max_filesize = 10M**

But it didn't worked for me.

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: Did you tried php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M in ".htaccess" file?

Comment: Neither `php.ini-dist` nor `php.ini-recommended` are actually used. You need to edit `php.ini`

Comment: @VinodVT no... How to restart the server? i dont know...

Comment: @Phil, there is no php.ini file in php directory...

Comment: @user3601333 try that in .htaccess file.

Comment: @Ankit, how? I have to create it first?

Comment: If you are using linux try this to restart $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @user3601333 .htaccess files are stored in the same directory as your .php files are. They modify configuration for that folder and all sub-folders. You simply use them by creating an .htaccess file in the directory of your choice (or modify it if present).

Comment: @user3601333 put it like this in your .htaccess file::: <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
   php_value post_max_size 40M
</IfModule>

Comment: @Ankit, but where can i find ".htaccess" file???

Comment: @user3601333 if you are using shared hosting then it should be in publicHtml folder. It is the same folder where all the files of your website are saved on server.

Comment: I haven't purchased the domain yet... I am using localhost right now...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you restart your server, if yes then
try to increase the mysql connect timeout in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the Apache Server after making any changes to configuration files.

Usually php.ini location is something like : **C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13**

You can check the location as per your machine.

And to restart wamp server, you can directly "Restart all services" via leftclick on Wamp Icon 
tray or close wamp server and start again.